# Field Calculator: Simple Python If-then and maths

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, if-else

I want to take all positive values in a field and multiply them by -1000. To do this, I put together the following code block:

```
def myCalc(x):
  if (x > 0):
    x*(-1000)
    return x
  else:
    return x
```

and then I call the expression:

```
myCalc( !FieldName! )
```

However, when I execute this field calculation, I get no warnings or errors, but the values in my field also don't change. The numbers look like this (before and after the calculation):

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reassign x to your calculation:

```
def myCalc(x):
    if (x > 0):
        x = x*(-1000)
        return x
    else:
        return x
```

If you'd like to save some typing you can simplify your logic a little:

```
def myCalc(x):
    if (x > 0):
        x = x*(-1000)
    return x
```

Comment: Thanks! It's been a while since I had to do logic like this. It's always the little things that I miss. :D